# Regex replace all occurences with something that is "derived" from the part to be replaced

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following line from a RTF document

```
10 \u8314?\u8805? 0
```

(which says in clear text `10 ⁺≥ 0`). You can see that the special characters are escaped with `\u` followed by the decimal unicode and by a question mark (which is the replacement character which should be printed in the case that displaying the special character is not possible). I want to have the text in a string variable in C# which is equivalent to the following variable:

```
string expected = "10 \u207A\u2265 0";
```

In the debugger I want to see the variable to have the value of `10 ⁺≥ 0`. I therefore must replace every occurence by the corresponding hexadecimal unicode (#207A = 8314 and #2265 = 8805). What is the simplest way to accomplish this with regular expressions?

Comment: What do you really want? Replace "\u8314?\u8805?" by "⁺≥" or by "\u207A\u2265"?

Comment: I want  to replace it with `⁺≥`. Too bad you deleted your answer. It was good except for the fact that I would go with `\d+` instead of `\d*`.

Comment: Undeleted. I prefer using \d+? because the + (plus) is greedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to parse the unicode representation of the RTF to a C# string.

So, the one-liner solution looks like this

```
string result = Regex.Replace(line, @"\\u(\d+?)\?", new MatchEvaluator(m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value)).ToString()));
```

But I suggest to use a cleaner code:

```
private static string ReplaceRtfUnicodeChar(Match match) {
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
    char chr = (char)number;
    return chr.ToString();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line= @"10 \u8314?\u8805? 0";

    var r = new Regex(@"\\u(\d+?)\?");
    string result = r.Replace(line, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceRtfUnicodeChar));

    Console.WriteLine(result); // Displays 10 ⁺≥ 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code is:

```
string str = @"10 \u8314?\u8805? 0";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(str, @"\\u([0-9]+)\?", match => {
    string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string hex = @"\u" + int.Parse(value).ToString("X4");
    return hex;
});
```

This will return

```
string line = @"10 \u207A\u2265 0";
```

so the `\u207A\u2265` won't be unescaped.

Note that the value is first converted to a number (`int.Parse(value)`) and then converted to a fixed-notation 4 digits hex number (`ToString("X4")`)

Or

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(str, @"\\u([0-9]+)\?", match => {
    string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
    char ch = (char)int.Parse(value);
    return ch.ToString();
});
```

This will return

```
string line = @"10 ⁺≥ 0";
```

Comment: After `\u` it is a decimal number, not a hex number. The question mark is part of the RTF syntax. I explained it in the question.

Comment: It should be `return (char)int.Parse(value)` otherwise `replaced` is `10 \\u207A\\u2265 0` and not `10 ⁺≥ 0`

Comment: @David Ah ok :-) You had asked for "it reads in clear text", so it wasn't clear what you really wanted. Added a second example. You were nearly right. You have to `ToString()` the `char`.

Comment: Your second code example does what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use MatchEvaluator:

```
string input = "10 \u8314?\u8805? 0";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\\u([A-Fa-f0-9]+)\?",RegexOptions.Multiline);
string result = reg.Replace(input, delegate(Match m) {
    return ConvertToWhatYouWant(m.Value); 
});
```